# CSS3: how to convert transition (direction) to transform?

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZrXr/

Simple CSS-transition-based drawer triggered by JQuery. The animation is still choppy on mobile Safari and I think the solution, besides implementing a plug-in like Green Sock, is to convert the act of transitioning the two divs to transforming them. Is this even possible?

```
#touchmenucanvas {
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition:left .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:left .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:left .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:left .2s ease-in-out;
    }

#touchmenudrawer {
    z-index:100;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:250px;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transition:right .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:right .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:right .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:right .2s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing Green Sock's Tween wont help you, since CSS3 transitions is (as of today) the most efficient way (in modern browsers of course) to animate elements.

However there are some tricks you can use to increase the performance, and that is *hardware acceleration.* HA occurs on the Grapical Processing Unit ("GPU") and takes care of the graphical calculations. This means that the CPU is freed and can perform various other tasks; keeping the browser nice and steady for example.

Not every browser support hardware acceleration though, but it automatically falls back to CPU-accelerated calculations when not (which is neat).

**Enough history lesson, lets dig into it**

What I'm talking about is the [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) property in CSS3, [translate3d](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp) to be exact. Use it in layout-free elements (position:absolute; for example) and it will transition smoothly. (it's GPU accelerated you remember?). Example (notice the browser compability):

```
#touchmenudrawer {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

And then let's say we move it 100px to the right:

```
#touchmenudrawer.toRight {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
```

Notice the syntax: *100px in x-axis, 0 in y-axis and 0 in z-axis.* Using `translate3d` instead of `translate` is what lets us perform magic. There are other ways of forcing GPU-accelerated transforms (rotating Y by 0deg etc.), but this one is my favourite and very clean.

You would use this technique to achieve your desired effect. Position the elements as you like, (left/right top/bottom etc.) and then animate them by changing their transform. This works very very well on iOS and is most likely the solution to your problem.

**But hang on, writing this for ALL my elements on the site, isn't that redundant?**

Well yes, and luckily for us there's a library that sorts the most of it out for you. If you are using jQuery you can use [jQuery transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), which basically wraps CSS3 transitions around the `$.animate()` method. It's not GPU-accelerated by default but can be achieved if you do a quick Google.

Comment: Eric, that's awesome. I did what you said and converted them to 3d translations. I updated my fiddle, but now my problem is closing the drawer. The animation resets to zero. What to do? http://jsfiddle.net/2ZrXr/1/

Comment: Skip the CSS3 keyframe-animations, use the paradigm I provided for you. Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZrXr/6/

Comment: Also, in the CSS why did you omit just transform and only use -webkit-transform? Is -webkit-transform enough for all browsers?

Comment: I say the same to you! Tell Kate I said hello! ;-)
You are pretty much set, but the rule is K.I.S.S. Keep It Simple Stupid; the more complex your element is, the more effort it takes to animate it. By reducing the markup and size (dimensions that is) of the element, you can achieve pretty sleek animations on the Apples!

And I used `-webkit-` only because I'm lazy, you shall use all the prefixes as in my post, to support all major browsers! May the coding force always be with you.

Comment: Kate... the love of my life. Every time I get onto a plane I just wish. Last question: the !important tag you added. I know it isn't necessary but should I keep them there?

Comment: Yeah I had to add it to override the default-value, try w/o and see what happens. If I remind myself correctly, it depends of which order you specify your class' in.

Comment: Everything works great. Any suggestions other than applying -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden to the elements to prevent flickering on mobile Safari? Only works on the canvas, not the drawer when it retracts back out of visibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56230/discussion-between-eric-and-oceanic815).